# How to determine if UserLocation lies above pin

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have a mapView and I'm showing a custom Pin icon and the Userlocation. Now I want to zoom out to show both on the map. Problem is that when the custom pin icon is above (north) of user location then the pin is cutted by mapView:

[image]

I know that I can use `[mapView setVisibleMapRect:[poly boundingMapRect] edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, 30, 30, 30) animated:YES]` to create a border but I would need a bigger one if the pin icon is above user icon and smaller if it's under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `latitude` of both points (or you can get them) and do a simple comparison to determine which is more northerly.